# Deny jQuery events during an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

On hover, I want to animate an div. During the animation I want to disable the hover possibility to avoid the animation call, several times. I removed the `mouseenter` event with `unbind`. Once the animation is finished the `mouseenter` event should be added again, but I'm not able to get this work.

Here is the jQuery:

```
items.hover(function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).unbind('mouseenter');
    if ($(this).hasClass('xy')) {
        $('div.block', this).addClass('xxx').removeClass('zzz').animate({
            top: '0'
        });
    }
}, function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('xy')) {
        $('div.block', this).animate({
            top: topHeightVal
        }, 200, function () {
            $(e.currentTarget).bind('mouseenter');
        }).addClass('zzz').removeClass('xxx');
    }
});
```

Comment: Add `if ($(e.is(":animated"))) return;` and remove the unbinding and binding from the event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd)

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Your code becomes

```
items.hover(function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).unbind('mouseenter');
    if ($(this).hasClass('xy')) {
        $('div.block', this).addClass('xxx').removeClass('zzz').stop(true, true).animate({
            top: '0'
        });
    }
}, function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('xy')) {
        $('div.block', this).stop(true, true).animate({
            top: topHeightVal
        }, 200).addClass('zzz').removeClass('xxx');
    }
});
```